# Convert hexadecimal strings from TBytes data in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a simple way of taking lines of hexadecimal data from a TStringList (always "Windows-1252" text files) and chopping them into record blocks (every line can be different length).

In Delphi 7 I used:

```
procedure DecodeLineAddr(const aLine: AnsiString; var ByteCount: integer; var Address:Cardinal; var RecType: Integer);
begin
//123 4567 89 0
//:10 4640 00 0000 0600 0200 fa00 004f 7800 1e00 fb00 88
 ByteCount:= StrToInt('$' + copy(aLine, 2, 2));
 Address  := StrToInt('$' + copy(aLine, 4, 4));
 RecType  := StrToInt('$' + copy(aLine, 8, 2));
end;
```

That is, just copy the chars from the correct positions in the initial "block info" in the line, then prepend a '$' so StrToInt would interpret the string as hex.

I process line-by-line - so it's easy enough to do something like:

```
aLineAsTBytes:= TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aStringLst[ndx]);
```

Then pass aLineAsTBytes into DecodeLineAddr as TBytes instead of AnsiString.

It isn't clear to me of how I should decode the various bytes (or how to carve them up appropriately) in order to return the correct results with code that will work on desktop and mobile.

That is, if using aLine:TBytes (instead of AnsiString), what's the equivalent of:

```
ByteCount:= StrToInt('$' + copy(aLine, 2, 2));
```

(and is there a better/faster way of handling this?)

TIA.

EdB

Comment: It's pretty hard to work out what you are asking. For sure there's going to be a faster way to do it.

Comment: Where is this source data coming from?  For desktop I can see a number of esoteric use cases where you might end up with clumsy hex-as-text data...but for mobile? Just what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @J... - the hex code will be loaded from file, converted (and validated) to a specific binary format which is sent over Bluetooth LE to update a microcontroller's flash memory. This from an Android or iOS device. I have it working in Windows over BT EDR using AnsiString - the (admittedly) clumsy hex-as-data is an industry standard - can't get away from it.  This is my first major port of a Delphi 7 program to XE8+ mobile - trying to get my head around not using AnsiString!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I have to use the hex-as-text data files - I used to just read the hex file into a TStringList and process each line as AnsiString - where it was simple to just copy the correct subset of chars and convert to integers.  I need to make this work on mobile. It's trivial to take a line from a TStringList and convert to TBytes - I'm just not sure of how I'd take the TBytes version and do the equivalent hex-as-text conversion to integer - or if there's a smarter way to accomplish this.

Comment: @edbord So, which industry standard are we talking about?  Which microcontroller?  The question I'm driving it at is whether or not you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @J...[intel hex format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX). About 4 different micros - and I'm definitely NOT re-inventing a wheel - the firmware flash programmers for each micro is custom - I've had the Win version since 2008 over CANBus - need to convert it to talk to custom firmware over BT. As I mentioned, I have it working quite nicely as a VCL app using AnsiStrings in D7.

Comment: So it sounds to me like your question isn't really around how to deal with the hex digits, but moreso on dealing with mobile strings in general.  It is really super annoying that they broke everything under the sun about strings on Mobile and dropped ansistring support.  But I was able to create a record type that reinstated ansi-string support essentially. The StrToint() calls you're making will work just fine if you are using the standard WideChar types... so really all you have to do is change AnsiString to string.

Comment: oh... and don't forget that strings are [0] based on mobile and copy() is technically deprecated.  I have a zcopy() method for you if you want it that works uniform across mobile and windows.

Comment: @JasonNelson - that's pretty much my problem - everything I've read on string compatibility in the past few days has done nothing but confuse me - and made me nervous. I was trying to move everything to TBytes so I could continue working with 1-byte arrays, instead of trying to work out the subtleties of ensuring I can process the hex file lines.  I don't know how to be sure I've captured the right chars, but I know where the bytes are. <sigh>  I wouldn't mind having a look at your zcopy, if only to help me understand the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're already doing will work but you'll need to make a few tweaks.  Most Importantly, make your function into a "string" type instead of an "AnsiString" type, which means that you'll have to convert it.

Mobile strings are 0-based, so on mobile you'll need to subtract 1 from your indexes.  Or you can use my ocopy() or zcopy() functions which both perform the same on all platforms.  Use ocopy() if you're dealing with old windows code, it will treat your 0-based strings as 1-based strings essentially, making it easier to port.

```
const
{$IFNDEF MSWINDOWS}
  STRZ = 1;
{$ELSE}
  STRZ = 0;
function zcopy(sString: string; iStartZeroBased: nativeint; iLength: nativeint):    string;
begin
  result := '';
  setlength(result, lesserof(iLength, length(sString)-iStartZerobased));
  movemem32(@result[strz], @sString[(strz+iStartZeroBased)],    length(result)*sizeof(char));
end;

function ocopy(sString: string; iStartOneBased: nativeint; iLength:     nativeint): string;
begin
  result := zcopy(sString, iStartOneBased-1, iLength);
end;
```

Next, take this code which isn't a totally complete solution, but will give you most of your ansi-string support on mobile (with some slight caveats around pointers).  But basically you can essentially convert strings by simply assigning an ansistring to a string type or vice verse.   I had to hack this away from a couple of dependencies so I don't guarantee that it will compile out of the box, but it should be pretty close.

```
unit iosbytestring;

interface

uses
  sysutils, classes;

{$IFNDEF MSWINDOWS}
const STRZERO = 0;
{$ELSE}
const STRZERO = 1;
{$ENDIF}

type
  Tiosansichar = packed record
  private
    b: byte;
    class function AnsiFromChar(c: char): byte;static;
    class function CharFromAnsi(b: byte): char;static;

  public
    function ToChar: char;
    function ToOrd: byte;
    class operator Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): string;
    class operator Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): char;
    class operator Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): byte;
    class operator Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): pointer;
  end;

  Tiosbytestring = record
  private
    Fbytes: TBytes;
    function GetChar(idx: nativeint): char;
    procedure SetChar(idx: nativeint; const Value: char);
    function GetAddrOf(idx: nativeint): pbyte;
    function getbyte(idx: nativeint): byte;
    procedure setbyte(idx: nativeint; const Value: byte);
  public
    property chars[idx: nativeint]: char read GetChar write SetChar;
    property bytes[idx: nativeint]: byte read getbyte write setbyte;
    property addrof[idx: nativeint]: pbyte read GetAddrOf;
    class operator Implicit(const s: TIOSByteString): string;
    class operator Implicit(const s: string): TIOSByteString;
    class operator Add(const s1,s2: TIOSByteString): TIOSByteSTring;
    class operator Add(const s1: string; const s2: TIOSByteString):     TIOSByteSTring;
    class operator Add(const s1: TIOSByteString; const s2: string): TIOSByteSTring;
    procedure FromString(s: string);
    function ToString: string;
    procedure SetLength(i: nativeint);
  end;
  TIOSAnsiString = TIOSByteString;
{$IFNDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ansistring = TIOSByteString;
  utf8string = TIOSByteString;
  widestring = string;
{$ENDIF}


implementation

{ iosbytestring }

class operator Tiosbytestring.Add(const s1: string;
const s2: TIOSByteString): TIOSByteSTring;
var
  ss2,ss3: string;
begin
  ss2 := s2.ToString;
  ss3 := s1+ss2;
  result.FromString(ss3);

end;

class operator Tiosbytestring.Add(const s1: TIOSByteString;
const  s2: string): TIOSByteSTring;
var
  ss1,ss3: string;
begin
  ss1 := s1.ToString;
  ss3 := ss1+s2;
  result.FromString(ss3);
end;




procedure Tiosbytestring.FromString(s: string);
begin
  Fbytes := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(s);

end;

function Tiosbytestring.GetAddrOf(idx: nativeint): pbyte;
begin
  result := @Fbytes[idx];
end;

function Tiosbytestring.getbyte(idx: nativeint): byte;
begin
  result := Fbytes[idx-strzero];
end;

function Tiosbytestring.GetChar(idx: nativeint): char;
begin
  result := Tiosansichar.CharFromAnsi(Fbytes[idx-strzero]);
end;

class operator Tiosbytestring.Implicit(const s: TIOSByteString): string;
begin
  result := s.ToString;

end;

class operator Tiosbytestring.Implicit(const s: string): TIOSByteString;
begin
  result.FromString(s);
end;

procedure Tiosbytestring.setbyte(idx: nativeint; const Value: byte);
begin
  Fbytes[idx-strzero] := value;
end;

class operator Tiosbytestring.Add(const s1,
  s2: TIOSByteString): TIOSByteSTring;
var
  ss1,ss2,ss3: string;
begin
  ss1 := s1.ToString;
  ss2 := s2.ToString;
  ss3 := ss1+ss2;
  result.FromString(ss3);

end;

procedure Tiosbytestring.SetChar(idx: nativeint; const Value: char);
begin
  Fbytes[idx-strzero] := Tiosansichar.AnsiFromChar(value);
end;

procedure Tiosbytestring.SetLength(i: nativeint);
begin
  system.setlength(Fbytes,i);
end;

function Tiosbytestring.ToString: string;
begin
  result := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(Fbytes);
end;

{ Tiosansichar }


class function Tiosansichar.AnsiFromChar(c: char): byte;
var
  s: string;
  te: TEncoding;
  b: TBytes;
begin
  s := c;

  b := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(c);
  result := b[0];


end;


class function Tiosansichar.CharFromAnsi(b: byte): char;
var
  s: string;
  bytes: TBytes;
begin
  system.setlength(bytes, 1);
  bytes[0] := b;
  s := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(bytes, 0, 1);
  result := s[low(s)];
end;

class operator Tiosansichar.Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): char;
begin
  result := s.ToChar;
end;

class operator Tiosansichar.Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): string;
begin
  result := s.ToChar;
end;

class operator Tiosansichar.Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): pointer;
begin
  result := @s.b;
end;

class operator Tiosansichar.Implicit(const s: Tiosansichar): byte;
begin
  result := s.b;
end;

function Tiosansichar.ToChar: char;
begin
  result := CharFromAnsi(b);
end;

function Tiosansichar.ToOrd: byte;
begin
  result := b;
end;

end.
```

So just add the above unit, add it to your uses clause, and magically, you'll have an ansistring type on your mobile platforms.  Continue using the standard ansistring type on windows.

If all is well... this is how your code snippet might end up looking.

```
procedure DecodeLineAddr(const aLine: AnsiString; var ByteCount: integer; var     Address:Cardinal; var RecType: Integer);
var
  aLineWide: string;
begin
  aLineWide = aLine;
  //123 4567 89 0
  //:10 4640 00 0000 0600 0200 fa00 004f 7800 1e00 fb00 88
  ByteCount:= StrToInt('$' + ocopy(aLineWide, 2, 2));
  Address  := StrToInt('$' + ocopy(aLineWide, 4, 4));
  RecType  := StrToInt('$' + ocopy(aLineWide, 8, 2));
end;
```

Comment: IF you decide to use my ansistring mobile replacement, pay close attention to the chars[] bytes[] and addrof[] properties.  @mystring[5] won't work, for example, but the equivalent is mystring.addrof[5] to get the address of a char.  Also you'll have to replace any code that uses ord(mystring[5]) with mystring[5].ToOrd

Comment: I should mention, that none of this is at all optimal, and I'm sure there will be a bunch of trolls who will whine about that... but it'll get the job done.

Comment: Also setlength(myString) doesn't work on my ansistring for mobile.  Use mystring.setlength() instead.  I suppose I should have thought to just make a global function in that unit.

procedure SetLength(s: TiosByteString; newlength: nativeint)
begin
  s.SetLength(newlength);
end;

Comment: Nice!  There's enough there to help me work out quite a few issues I've had in "getting my head around this". Thanks - this will be very useful in moving me forward - out of D7 into something a little more modern.

Comment: Good!  I'm glad to see people upgrading from Delphi 7... maybe I'll be able to find another Delphi job someday lol.  I like Delphi, I hope it gets back on its feet and more companies start using the updated versions.

Comment: "I hope it gets back on its feet"? It is not only on its feet, it is running very well.

Comment: That's not what the job market is telling me.  Try doing a search for Delphi jobs in the ENTIRE USA and tell me how many you find.  Also, try just asking Google for the answers to some Delphi questions, you'll get more links to blogs trolling about inaction rather than answers.  That, to me, says that no one in the USA is using it.  The only blogs out there that actually offer any information out there are the typically ones produced internally at Embarcadero.